# Symfony2 - Expanded choice (form) does not set default value(s)

Tags: forms, symfony

Having the following code in the form:

```
        ->add('groups', 'model', array(
              'class' => 'FOS\UserBundle\Propel\Group',
              'required' => true,
              'multiple' => true,
              'expanded' => true,
              'query' => GroupQuery::create()->orderByName(),
          ))
```

This renders the checkboxes correctly, but does not set the defaultvalues.
When I set "expanded => false", it becomes a select list, but then the default values are set correctly.. Bug in Symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug when you use propel instead of doctrine.

I had the same problem as you and found out why it isnt working.
There is a function in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php  named getValuesForChoices.
This function compares 2 objects with '==='. In doctrine, this works but it returns false if you use Propel.

```
public function getValuesForChoices(array $choices)
{
    $choices = $this->fixChoices($choices);
    $values = array();

    foreach ($choices as $i => $givenChoice) {
        foreach ($this->choices as $j => $choice) {
            if ($choice === $givenChoice) {
                $values[$i] = $this->values[$j];
                unset($choices[$i]);

                if (0 === count($choices)) {
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $values;
}
```

This is the function where it fails.
The comparing will fail because the objects has difference numbers
example:
It trys to compare this:
object(Vendor\Bundle\Model\Tag)#506
object(Vendor\Bundle\Model\Tag)#397

**NOTE: This is not a fix but a explain of the problem.**

Whenever i use the propel function to check if the objects are equal, the checkboxes are filled:

```
public function getValuesForChoices(array $choices)
{
    $choices = $this->fixChoices($choices);
    $values = array();
    foreach ($choices as $i => $givenChoice) {

        foreach ($this->choices as $j => $choice) {

            if ($choice->equals($givenChoice)) {
                $values[$i] = $this->values[$j];
                unset($choices[$i]);

                if (0 === count($choices)) {
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $values;
}
```

Another interesting thing is the InstancePooling of propel.

From the documentation:
http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#propel-instance-pool

> Propel keeps a list of the objects that you already retrieved in
>   memory to avoid calling the same request twice in a PHP script. This
>   list is called the instance pool, and is automatically populated from
>   your past requests. The instance pool is consulted whenever searching
>   for an object using its primary key via findPk or findOneById (which
>   is an alias for the former).

However, i'm just a beginner and i don't know very much about propel and symfony, so i don't know why this isnt working.